# Getting SPAWN EPERM on running Authorize and Open Default Org commands

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, node.js

I am getting SPAWN EPERM error while running the sfdx authorize and open default org commands from both vs code and command line.

[image]

Comment: From Googling, security products or firewalls can be a cause. See e.g. [Use the Salesforce CLI from Behind a Company Firewall or Web Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm).

Comment: I am on my home network. I don't think proxy should be the issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is resolved. The issue in my case was there were certain policies that my company had set in my system that was blocking the execution of those commands.

Comment: Is it possible to please potentially expand on this answer? I am having the same issue, and suspect the same cause, but unsure on where to find the 'policies'.

Answer (score 0):

For authorizing the org, try the below command
**sfdx force:auth:device:login**
It will give you the code and URL. Put the URL in the browser and enter the code. It will ask for credentials. Enter your credentials and complete the process.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this is an answer to _this question_.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/193654)

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue. I identified from the sf cli logs that this was being triggered when the 'open' core-plugin was attempting to use Powershell. (open/index.js lines 171:173).

Powershell on our corporate devices is blocked, and hence the error was being thrown. I have submitted an Issue on github for this. But enabling access to Powershell was the fix for me.